# Как вызвать функцию в методе в зависимости от типа модели

Tags: c#

Есть основной класс где много функций и есть 2-3 типа модели которые определяться при инициализации основного класса(каждый тип модели имеет свой класс с одинаковым названием функций, но с разной реализацией). В каждой функции основного класса должна быть проверка на тип модели и в зависимости от типа модели должна вызываться функция

**Main class**

```
public class TelnetConnection
    {
        static int TAIMAUT = 7000;
        S_Switch dataSwitch;
        public TelnetConnection(string ip_device, string typeModel,string version, int port)
        {
            dataSwitch.ip_device = ip_device;
            dataSwitch.typeModel = identifyDevice(typeModel);
            dataSwitch.version = version;
            dataSwitch.port = port;
        }

        TypeModel identifyDevice(string typeModel) { 
        
            if(typeModel == "Eltex")
            {
               return TypeModel.Eltex;
            }
            else if (typeModel == "Qtech")
            {
                return TypeModel.Qtech;
            }

            return TypeModel.Null;
        }
Много функций класса...
```

Comment: Вот эта вся ерунда `if(typeModel == "Eltex")` пишется в одну строку, без перечислений (`Enum.TryParse(...);`). А то, что вы спрашиваете - зовется "Состоянием". И да, в C# принято писать все в CamelCase, где публичные методы идут с заглавной буквы, без лишних знаков, пробелов и прочего, каждое слово с большой буквы. То есть не `ip_device`, а `IpDevice`, `identifyDevice` -> `IdentifyDevice`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да все верно, состояние это то что мне нужно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно использовать один из основных принципов ООП - [Полиморфизм](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism). Из документации MSDN:

> Вы можете использовать полиморфизм выполнив 2 простых шага:
>
> 1. Создать иерархию классов, состоящую из базового класса и дочерних, наследуемые от базового.
> 2. Использовать виртуальный метод в базовом классе и модификатор 'override' в дочернем классе, чтобы изменить реализацию базового класса

Если реализация для каждой модели своя и нет необходимости создавать объект базового класса, можно базовый класс сделать [абстрактным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members) или использовать [интерфейс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface).